# Stop Mouse Pointer from Changing When Over Buttons & Text

Tags: pointers, mouse

Is there a property that will stop the mouse pointer from changing to a hand when over a button or a text cursor when over unmodifiable text?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language and any framework you're using.

Answer (score 2):

it depends what environment you are talking about. (desktop applications? websites?)

in almost every scenario you can somehow do that.

if you are talking about websites
there is an easy way:

just define the [css cursor attribute](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470321/CSS-and-Cursors.htm) as you desire.

[read more about css here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and [have a tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), its free.

Comment: Great thanks, I have been going through the W3 school tutorials and didn't realize the answer was right in front of my face.